# Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Number and Number

Tags: excel, powerquery

I don't understand the root of this Type issue. I have added a custom column to combine two numbers. They are both Type123. I am unsure why the error pops up.

[image: Number Data]

[image: Custom Colum]

[image]

Comment: Change the type to text. Or you could use `Number.ToText`.

Comment: That worked. I not sure I understand why though.

Comment: Numbers need changed to text before being able to be concatenated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write below expression in custom column

=Number.ToText([Patient Chart Number])&"."&Number.ToText([Visit Number])

This should work.

Comment: Got any guidance on learning more on data types in general? Looks like I could use the reading.

Comment: Hi, I believe you get a full list of functions as below. Query Editor -> New Table & in formula tab type "= #shared" & Power BI will list all functions & table. You can check the syntax of each function on MS Website. I am not sure if I answered your query.